# filter homepage content based on term id

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have two pages "homepage" and "countries", the default behavior is that when a visitor first visit my homepage all content is gathered regardless of the country.

But if the user went to the countries page, which is a view that's getting term ids from a taxonomy list, and selects a country, he/she will get redirected to the homepage and the homepage content will get filtered to the term id the person chose from the countries page.

I think I should be using contextual filters, but I'm confused right now.

my question is how can I do this filter on homepage based on a term clicked from another view.

any help will be greatly appreciated with hot cookies.

Comment: Yes, you should use contextual filters. But what is your question? And please consider to reformat your post, so it is easier to read. =)

Comment: thanks for the reply, i reformatted a bit, and added my question. hope to get answers soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, now i understand your problem!

When a user clicks on a link in the "countries" page, he will see the standard taxonomy term "view". But i guess you want him to see your normal "homepage" BUT with filtered content.

You have two options:

1. Alter the taxonomy term page.
2. Use contextual filter on the "homepage" and change the links on the "countries" page according to use the filter.

In my opinion you should clearly prefer option two. Also have a look at the view "Glossary", which should be included, but not activated out of the box, this should help you a lot in configuration!

Comment: lol, did not understood "community wiki". Can an admin change that? Or just go on and improve my answer =)